# How to apply a style to the first WPF ContentPresenter found under a gridview but not any deeper

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to be able to style the ContentPresenter used for rendering the cells of a GridView. However if I set a style targeting ContentPresenter generally then it will target ContentPresenter instances within ContentPresenters which I do not want to do. I only want to style the first level of content presenters found.

Is this possible? Something like this

```
<Style Target="GridView">
    <Style.Resource>
        <Style Target="ContentPresenter" Depth=1>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

where Depth=1 is an invented property.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do this with a DataTemplateSelector - by setting a style for a ContentPresenter and ensuring it used a [ContentTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx).

My example is simplified and doesn't use a GridView - but the concept is the same.

If you had the following DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class DepthTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate InDepthTemplate { get; set; }

    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public int Depth { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var next = container;
        int itemsControlCount = 0;

        while (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(next) != null)
        {
            var current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(next);
            if (current.GetType() == this.Type)
            {
                itemsControlCount++;
            }

            next = current;
        }



        if (itemsControlCount <= this.Depth)
        {
            return this.InDepthTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Then wire this up in XAML with whatever template you wanted to use for content presenters with less than a certain depth:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:w="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <w:DepthTemplateSelector x:Key="DepthTemplateSelector" Depth="2" Type="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <w:DepthTemplateSelector.InDepthTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type w:Model}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="Red" />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </w:DepthTemplateSelector.InDepthTemplate>
    </w:DepthTemplateSelector>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource DepthTemplateSelector}" />
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type w:Model}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <w:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" />
</Window>
```

So the XAML creates and configures the DataTemplateSelector but also ensures all ContentPresenters use it by setting a default ContentPresenter style.

This will then give you the following effect (with Depth set to 2):

[image: screenshot]

This is based on the following view model, which uses a recursive structure to illustrate the point:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Models = new List<Model>
            {
                new Model
                    {
                        Description = "ModelA", 
                        Models = new List<Model>
                            {
                                new Model { Description = "ModelA1" },
                                new Model { Description = "ModelA2" }
                            }
                    },
                new Model
                    {
                        Description = "ModelB", 
                        Models = new List<Model>
                            {
                                new Model { Description = "ModelB1" },
                                new Model
                                    {
                                        Description = "ModelB2", 
                                        Models = new List<Model>
                                            {
                                                new Model { Description = "ModelB2i" },
                                                new Model { Description = "ModelB2ii" }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            };
    }

    public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
}
```